# MongoDB Replica Set election fails with "no replset config has been received" response from peers

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to establish a replica set with three members (one of which is an arbiter). For technical reasons the members must access each other using SSH tunnelling. I am reasonably confident this is configured correctly as on all the mongodb host's I am able to connect to the other nodes using mongo by providing the relevant --host and --port parameters. When I initiate the replica set on what I'd like to be the primary, the logs show the "initiator" successfully connecting to the other members:

```
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to RECOVERING
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to SECONDARY
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member 10.x.x.1:27017 is now in state STARTUP
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member 10.x.x.2:27017 is now in state STARTUP
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Starting an election, since we've seen no PRIMARY in the past 10000ms
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] conducting a dry run election to see if we could be elected
```

However, the other members refuse to vote as they don't have any configuration for the replica set

```
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] VoteRequester: Got error processing response with status: BadValue: Unexpected field info in ReplSetRequestVotes, resp:{ info: "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set", ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no replset config has been received", code: 94 }
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] VoteRequester: Got no vote from 10.16.10.4:30000 because: , resp:{ info: "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set", ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no replset config has been received", code: 94 }
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] VoteRequester: Got error processing response with status: BadValue: Unexpected field info in ReplSetRequestVotes, resp:{ info: "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set", ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no replset config has been received", code: 94 }
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] VoteRequester: Got no vote from 10.16.10.4:27018 because: , resp:{ info: "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set", ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no replset config has been received", code: 94 }
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] not running for primary, we received insufficient votes
```

This process repeats every electionTimeoutMillis.

running rs.status() on the intiator of the replica set gives a suspicious time for the last heartbeat received from each member

```
> rs.status()
...
"lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
...
```

I'm not sure what's cause and effect here. Will a member of the replica set only receive the configuration after the "initiator" has received the heartbeat response? Is there a way to force the initiator to send the configuration to the other members?